# Deallocation of memory if functionality never terminates

Tags: c++

i have allocated memory dynamically with NEW and functionality in which it is implemented  will be always keep on running,when i will forcefully terminate it will exit.i Want to deallocate memory also .how i can do that ?

Comment: Dynamically allocated memory will be reclaimed when your process dies.

Comment: please be specific or some sample code here not able to get your problem

Answer (score 4):

If the block where you are allocating memory is executed multiple times, then you should think about using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) to deallocate the memory when those objects go out of scope, without you calling delete explicitly.

If the block is executed only once and you want to deallocate memory when the program exits, that is not needed as the OS will reclaim all the memory allocated to your process, irrespective of whether the memory is explicitly deallocated within the process.